# C# :- Loop over 4 Dictionaries

Tags: c#

I've 4 Dictionaries like,

```
Dictionary<string, string> home = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> home1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> away1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> away2= new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

now I want to perform Assert for each of them on their Keys and values. How should i do that ?

i was thinking to adding them as below,

```
var dic = new[] { home , home1 , away1 , away2};
```

and then use Switch but it seems difficult as switch can't be used on array. So how should i approach this one ?

Comment: Well what is wrong with your try? are you getting any error or Exception?

Comment: You want to assert on each `KeyValuePair<string, string>` in each `Dictionary<string, string>`?  How about `foreach (var pair in dic.SelectMany(x => x)) { // Assert on 'pair' }`.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Thanks for your Foreach loop but now i have to run the different Assert conditions on each Pair . How can i find out which one is which pair ? I means can we able to get dic. names ? so i can run the switch inside ?

Comment: You are performing a different assert for each dictionary?  If that is the case then why not just use four different `foreach` loops?

Comment: @JasonBoyd yes i have used it already after putting this post but was wondering if any shortcut for this . You think so any shortcut can be used ?

Comment: Not that I can see.  Sometimes the straightforward solution is the best solution.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Ok got it . Atleast can you able to help me to write this in a foreach loop in one line (with Lamda or Linq) so at least loop will in one line .

     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> js in awaywickets)
            {

                Assert.True(js.Key.Contains("Wickets"));
                Assert.True(js.Value != null);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a function for asserting a dictionary, then loop over the array and call it, something like this:

```
foreach (var element in dic)
{
    AssertOnDictioanry(element);
}
```

Hope this was useful.